# Searching for T-shirt not returning t-shirt in elasticsearch

Tags: magento, elasticsearch, search, magento2

I am using the following settings and mappings for elasticSearch

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 10
        },
        "synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms":[
            "yoga,fit-sports,blue",
            "tshirt,tees,t-shirt "
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "synonym_filter",
            "autocomplete_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "products": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          },
          "analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I indexed a field "name:Princess Print T-shirt".

As am using whitespace analyzer, es create token like "t-shirt".
but for searching i am using "search_analyzer": "standard" the query i think is going like "princess print t shirt" and this "t shirt" will not match thus will give empty search result.
One solution from my side is like adding synonym like "t shirt,t-shirt". Then i will get the result. but in this case if we search for "shirt" it will return both "t-shirt and shirt" which is not acceptable.
And if i didn't use this "search_analyzer": "standard" i am not getting expected result.
If i search for "t-shirt" i need only tat search result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem description

The problematic part is as you already described `"search_analyzer": "standard"`.

This will transform every entry of `T-shirt` to the tokens `t` and `shirt`.
The data in your index looks like `t-shirt`, `t-shir` and so on and does not match.

## Possible solution

### Adapt search analyzer

You need to make sure that the query is lowercased, splitted at whitespace.
So you could define also a custom anlyzer for query time using the `whitespace analyzer` https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-analyzer.html combined with a lowercase-analyzer.

Comment: Thanks a-lot @ Andreas. I created a custom analyzer with whitespace and lowercase filter for search_analyzer... works well..!